# using references inside a namespace vs root level

Tags: c#, .net

What's the advantage of doing this:

```
namespace a
{
    using System;

    class ClassA
    {

    }
}
```

over this

```
using System;

namespace a
{
     class ClassA
     {
     }
}
```

is there any performance advantage or best practices?

Answer (score 3):

There's definitely no performance difference at runtime since namespace resolution is done at compile time, and I doubt there's a significant compile time difference either.

All the C# code I've seen has the `using` statements at the top of the file, so I'd consider that more "normal".

Comment: thanks for the reply. i have found the answer in the other post where this question has already been answered. i have marked my question as duplicate.